# Finding an instance of a private class in a separate assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project, I am utilizing a networking library which, understandably, also keeps track of inbound/outbound traffic. However for some reason, the developer decided to leave this info only available in the editor, instead of making it publicly accessible at runtime. But, I would like to do some traffic benchmarking, and change my code flow at runtime depending on traffic.

Using reflection, I could easily get an instance to the internal class (and private field) which keeps track of networked traffic, but this does not resolve anything because it won't be the same instance that the actual separate assembly utilizes, so the value will always be zero.

So... Is there any way to find a valid instance of a known class inside an assembly which my project references?

Comment: If you have an instance of a public class which has private/internal members that lead to the instance you want, then you can follow the trail down with reflection..

Comment: The class `EventReliableSendBuffer` is marked as Internal, and the desired field `count` is marked as private, and there is no guarantee that the library uses a singleton instance. There may be multiple over a period of time. Could reflection still be used here?

Comment: I do not know of a way to just "find all instances" on a class. I suspect it's not possible. I don't know what library you're using, or how it works.. I suggest you root around some more with reflector. Pretend everything is public: how would you get the field you want starting with the public instance that you have? `networkingManagerThingy.publicField.privateField.sendBuffer.count`? Use reflection to jump the gaps that you can't get over because of access modifiers.

Comment: Okay so after poking around the library's source code a bit, and seeing how it handles what I'm trying to achieve, I managed to find a more public namespace which actually does provide what I'm going for. But to accurately utilize it, I still had to use reflection on a private field to determine when the value actually has changed.

Comment: And in case you're wondering why I didn't just change the source code (since I do actually have access to it), it's because it can't compile on my machine due to certain requirements that my machine can't legally meet.